# Hide the 3rd paragraph out of 5 paragraphs on a click of a button, with out assigning any class or id to the paragraphs

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have five paragraphs on my front end as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div">
        <p>para1</p>
        <p>para2</p>
        <p>para3</p>
        <p>para4</p>
        <p>para5</p>
        <asp:Button id="button" runat="server" Text="Click to hide para3!" />     
    </div>
</form>
```

In JS I wrote the following:

```
 $("#button").click(function () {
    $('#div').find('p').hide();
    return false;
});
```

I know when I click on the `button` it hides all the `p` tags, so it would be great if any one can tell me how I would be able to hide the third paragraph only.

Comment: in pure JS just do `div.children[2].hidden = true;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `eq()` method to specify which element in a matched set you want to retrieve by its index. As the index is zero-based, to get the third element would be `eq(2)`.

Also note that you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element, not the `click` event of the button. Firstly because it's much better practice and secondly because you're using ASP.Net web forms which means that the `id` attributes will be over-written on any `runat="server"` elements when the HTML is generated by the server (unless you specify a setting but that's not specifically relevant here).

Try this:

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div">
        <p>para1</p>
        <p>para2</p>
        <p>para3</p>
        <p>para4</p>
        <p>para5</p>
        <asp:Button id="button" runat="server" Text="Click to hide para3!" />     
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div').find('p:eq(2)').hide();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/e91gpdmz/)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `nth-child(n)` selector selects all elements that are the `nth child`, regardless of type, of their parent.
So you can do it with this way:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $('#div p:nth-child(3)').hide();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It would help to educate the questioner if you told them what you changed and why it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use jquery's `.eq()`.
this method reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

For more [Jquery's`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#div p').eq(2).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
    <div id="div">
        <p>para1</p>
        <p>para2</p>
        <p>para3</p>
        <p>para4</p>
        <p>para5</p>
        <button id="button">Click to hide para3</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
   $('#div').find('p:nth-child(3)').hide()
   return false;
});
```

`:nth-child(' + number + ')` will give the child at 'Number' position.

Comment: It would help to educate the questioner if you told them what you changed and why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Let's play. (wont not work on Safari or IE due to arrows though)

```js
button.onclick = e => div.children[2].hidden = !div.children[2].hidden;
```

```html
<form id="form1">
    <div id="div">
        <p>para1</p>
        <p>para2</p>
        <p>para3</p>
        <p>para4</p>
        <p>para5</p>
        <button id="button">Click to hide para3</button>
    </div>
</form>
```